# MySQL time complexity for searching a record in a table

Tags: mysql, time-complexity

Suppose I have a table with n records in MySQL, what would be the time complexity for searching a record based on some criteria (say id = n-1)? Is it a linear time complexity or it has a constant time complexity ?
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you index the column, then the records will be binary-tree sorted, so it will be very fast. I'm not too familiar with all the optimizations, but theoretically at the very least it would be O(log n).

You can create the index with the `create index` MySQL command.

`create index id_index on MyTable (ID);`

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what kind of index you got on id. But if id is an integer, and n is a constant, then it can run in log(n) with an index on id.